# Retrieving Recently changed Profile Pictures in android app.?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I am developing android app. and for this i'm fetching user details from facebook.

I can able to get the current profile picture in my app. But i want to include recently changed profile pictures also in my app.

How can i get it using graph api or some other means. ?

Kindly help i'm stuck with this for last 2 days .. ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this link

https://graph.facebook.com/me/fql?q=select+pid,src_small+from+photo+where+aid+in(select+aid+from+album+where+owner=me()+and+type="profile")&access_token=...